# EXC_BAD_ACCESS Error with NSDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, memory-management

When I fetch data from a JSON file I get an error -> `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` .

I am not using ARC, here's my code:

```
    -(void)fetchedData:(NSData*)responseData
{
    NSError *error;
    NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:&error];

    fetchedResutsArray = [json objectForKey:@"People"];

    NSLog(@"%@", fetchedResutsArray);
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    //OrderCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    // Configure the cell...
    NSDictionary *resultsDict = [fetchedResutsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.text = [resultsDict objectForKey:@"prename"];

    return cell;
}
```

This is my JSON-Result. I get the data from a website
JSON:

```
 {
        prename = "Tim";
        lastname = "Test";
        username = "tim23";  
    },
        {
        prename = "John";
        lastname = "Test";
        username = "johniii";  
    },
        {
        prename = "Peter";
        lastname = "Test";
        username = "tenek23";        
    }
```

Xcode is showing this in NSLOG.

Comment: can you pls share ur json structure?

Comment: No i am not using ARC

Comment: Post the result you are getting in nslog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
fetchedResutsArray = [json objectForKey:@"People"];
```

This creates an autoreleased object which will be released sooner or later. You must not access this object outside of that method. You are violating memory management rules.

You can retain the object, which should solve your problem.

```
[fetchedResutsArray release]; // release old instance
fetchedResutsArray = [[json objectForKey:@"People"] retain];
```

Or use a retain @property and assign the object by using `self.fetchedResutsArray = [json objectForKey:@"People"];`. 
Don't forget to release the object in `dealloc`

Or just use ARC.

Comment: I'd go with the 'Just use ARC'  bit ^.^ as it makes your life so much easier.